# Cacheble annotation throws class cast exception

Tags: spring, caching, arraylist, annotations, hazelcast

I'm using Spring's Cacheable annotation to cache the results of a method which are of MyArrayList type:

```
@Cacheable(value = "list-cache", key = "'list.' + #name")
public MyArrayList<ListItem> getListItems(String name) 
{
}
```

The class MyArrayList is a subclass of ArrayList:

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> 
{
}
```

When the objects are retrieved using the cache a class cast exception is thrown:

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to pub.MyArrayList
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to pub.MyArrayList
    pub.controller.HomeController.getListItems(HomeController.java:28)
    pub.controller.HomeController.test(HomeController.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I'm using hazelcast as a cache manager. When I inspect the Map, I can observe that values are stored as a ArrayList, which later cannot be cast to proper types.

Is it possible to store classes which extend ArrayList using Spring annotations and hazelcast cache manager?

Comment: Can you show the content of `getListItems`? I don't know Hazelcast but that does not make any sense to me. Which `CacheManager` implementation do you use by the way?

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll: The cache manager is using Spring implementation: `<bean id="hazelcastCacheManager" class="com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager" c:hazelcastInstance-ref="hazelcast" />`

Comment: Have you configured serialization on disk by any chance? Maybe Hazelcast has some kind of special handling that just store the items of your collection but not the collection type itself

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll: No, they are cached using Map in memory: `<hz:map name="list-cache" time-to-live-seconds="300" />`

Comment: @pveentjer: I've updated the question with full stacktrace